# Unity character flies easily

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, rigid-bodies

I have been using Unity for a while and still Im not sure about some things, I know there are like 5 different ways to move our character (not using prefabs like for 1st or 3rd person controller I mean just code from scratch) so far for moving a character on a terrain I think setting the speed of the rigidbody works overal for me, just setting the x and leaving the y component as what it was before assigning that, so that gravity effect is kept, overal it works, I manage to collide with wall and other objects, manage to go on terrain and could add jump later in same fashion, but the trouble I find is that my character flies when it steps over any small object like a stone on ground, if he goes over it he starts flying, not a big distance but definetly looks like walking on the moon maybe, also I see that if I have a bridge that is lower in the middle part of it (like U shape) well the character goes like flying from the begining almost until the middle or so, as said works like being on the moon, however gravity seems ok on other objects, I know I can change the gravity value to be higher but Im affraid I could be breaking all that so my question is, is there a better way to move a character on ground that will work better without changing the gravity value? I guess that it can work right without affecting this value, I used other method to change velocity and adding a certain value to the y component but again I see it not right as an apparent correct value for small stones and small objects makes it hard to go over slopes too, any help is greatly welcome =).